# Why does echo "$out" split output onto multiple lines, if quotes suppress word-splitting?

Tags: bash, quoting

I have very simple directory with "directory1" and "file2" in it.
After

```
out=`ls`
```

I want to print my variable: `echo $out` gives:

```
directory1   file2
```

but `echo "$out"` gives:

```
directory1
file2
```

so using quotes gives me output with each record on separate line. As we know `ls` command prints output using single line for all files/dirs (if line is big enough to contain output) so I expected that using double quotes prevents my shell from splitting words to separate lines while ommitting quotes would split them. 
Pls tell me: why using quotes (used for prevent word-splitting) suddenly splits output ?

Comment: It doesn't split anything, the result contains newlines, using quotes gives you the exact string, including the newlines. Also someone will likely be along soon telling you not to parse `ls`.

Comment: Don't parse `ls`

Comment: Oh. I probably should have addressed this in my answer: ""As we know ls command prints output using single line for all files/dirs (if line is big enough to contain output)"" <- that's only true by default when output is to a TTY, *not* when output is to a pipeline, file, etc. (And POSIX doesn't *require* it to be true for a TTY either, so that's a piece of implementation-defined behavior).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### On Behavior Of `ls`

`ls` only prints multiple filenames on a single line by default *when output is to a TTY*. When output is to a pipeline, a file, or similar, then the default is to print one line to a file.

Quoting from [the POSIX standard for `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), with emphasis added:

> **The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals** or when one of the -C, -m, or -x options is specified. **If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.**

---

#### Literal Question (Re: Quoting)

It's the very act of splitting your command into separate arguments that causes it to be put on one line! *Natively*, your value spans multiple lines, so echoing it unmodified (without any splitting) prints it precisely that manner.

The result of your command is something like:

```
 out='directory1
 file2'
```

When you run `echo "$out"`, that *exact* content is printed. When you run `echo $out`, by contrast, the behavior is akin to:

```
echo "directory1" "file2"
```

...in that the string is split into two elements, each passed as completely different argument to `echo`, for `echo` to deal with as it sees fit -- in this case, printing both those arguments on the same line.

---

#### On Side Effects Of Word Splitting

Word-splitting may *look* like it does what you want here, but that's often not the case! Consider some particular issues:

- Word-splitting expands glob expressions: If a filename contains a `*` surrounded by whitespace, that `*` will be replaced with a list of files in the current directory, leading to duplicate results.
- Word-splitting doesn't honor quotes or escaping: If a filename contains whitespace, that internal whitespace can't be distinguished from whitespace separating multiple names. This is closely related to the issues described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

---

#### On Reading Directories

See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In short -- in your example of `` out=`ls` ``, the `out` variable (being a string) isn't able to store all possible filenames in a useful, parsable manner.

Consider, for instance, a file created as such:

```
touch $'hello\nworld"three words here"'
```

...that filename contains spaces and newlines, and word-splitting won't correctly detect it as a single name in the output from `ls`. However, you *can* store and process it in an array:

```
# create an array of filenames
names=( * )
if ! [[ -e $names || -L $names ]]; then  # this tests only the FIRST name
  echo "No names matched" >&2            # ...but that's good enough.
else
  echo "Found ${#files[@]} files" # print number of filenames
  printf '- %q\n' "${names[@]}"
fi
```

Comment: Nice! This is very descriptive.